# Working with private types in Ada to create a private int

Tags: ada

I am trying to implement a private type in Ada like it is used in Java or C++. For example I want to have a "private int" in Ada.

As I have found here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Object_Orientation#Encapsulation:_public.2C_private_and_protected_members I have to implement my variable in the package body. So I have tried to implement this like it is described on the example.

My problem is that I can't create a Create function for creating an object and set the values. My second problem is that I want to have children of this type. These children should have a Create function which sets the values for the masterclass and the subclass.

Here is my code which is not working. I have added comments on the points which is not working.

```
private with Ada.Finalization;
package MasterClass is
    type MasterC is tagged private;    
    type MasterC_Class_Ref is access all MasterC'Class;
    procedure printNumObjects;
    procedure do( This : in MasterC );
    function Make (f1, f2 : Float) return MasterC;
    function getVar(This : MasterC) return float;  
private
    type Private_Part;  -- declaration stub
    type Private_Part_Pointer is access Private_Part;

    type Private_Component is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with record
        P: Private_Part_Pointer;
    end record;
    overriding procedure Initialize (X: in out Private_Component);
    overriding procedure Adjust     (X: in out Private_Component);
    overriding procedure Finalize   (X: in out Private_Component);

    type MasterC is tagged record
        P : Private_Component;
    end record;
end MasterClass;

package body MasterClass is
    numObjects : Integer := 0;      
    type Private_Part is record  -- complete declaration
        fTest1, fTest2 : float := 0.0;
    end record;

    overriding procedure Initialize (X: in out Private_Component) is
    begin
        X.P := new Private_Part'(fTest1=>0.0, fTest2 => 0.0);
    end Initialize;

    overriding procedure Adjust (X: in out Private_Component) is
    begin
        X.P := new Private_Part'(fTest1 => X.P.fTest1, fTest2 => X.P.fTest2);
    end Adjust;

    overriding procedure Finalize (X: in out Private_Component) is
        procedure Free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation (Private_Part, Private_Part_Pointer);
    begin
        Free (X.P);
    end Finalize;
        
    function Make (f1, f2 : Float ) return MasterC is   
    begin
        numObjects := numObjects + 1;
        return new MasterC'(fTest1=>0.0, fTest2=>0.0); -- This is not working!      
    end Make;

    procedure do( This : in MasterC ) is
    begin
        Put_Line( "doneMaster");
    end do;
    
    function getVar( This : MasterC )
        return float is
    begin
        return This.P.P.fTest1;  -- This is not working!
    end getVar; 
end MasterClass;

with MasterClass; use MasterClass;
package SubClass is 
    type SubC is new MasterClass.MasterC with 
        record
            fExtra1 : float := 0.0;
            fExtra2 : float := 0.0;
        end record;     
    type SubC_Class_Ref is access all SubC'Class;   
    overriding procedure do(This : SubC);
    function Make (f1, f2 : Float) return SubC; 
    function Make1 (f1, f2 , w, h: Float) return SubC;
end SubClass;

with MasterClass; use MasterClass;
package body SubClass is
    function Make ( f1, f2 : Float ) return SubC is
    begin       
        return ((fTest1 => f1, fTest2 => f2, fExtra1 => 0.0, fExtra2 => 0.0));      
    end Make;

    function Make1 ( f1, f2, w, h: Float ) return SubC is
    begin       
        return (fTest1 => f1, fTest2 => f2, fExtra1 => w, fExtra2 => h);        
    end Make1;

    overriding procedure do( This : in SubC ) is
    begin
        do(MasterC(This));
        Put_Line( "doneSub");
    end do;
end SubClass;
```

I cant find any information how to implement this.

The lines which I don't how to implement is the return line in the Make function

```
return new MasterC'(fTest1=>0.0, fTest2=>0.0); -- This is not working!
```

Then the line for reading the values

```
return This.P.P.fTest1;  -- This is not working!
```

And then the line in the Make function for the Subclass.

```
return ((fTest1 => f1, fTest2 => f2, fExtra1 => 0.0, fExtra2 => 0.0)); -- This is not working!
```

Comment: Does the compiler give you an error on `return This.P.P.fTest1`?  If so, what?  I'm at home and don't have a compiler handy.

Comment: Thank you very much. With your edits this is working for me. One question. What happens if I have a SuhClass of the SubClass. A new SubSubClass. This one shouldnt add any new components to the SubClass but it should have his own Make function. My Problem is that SubSubClass.Make returns type SubSubClass. If I add "return SubClass.Make(...)" I am getting the error that it needs a type SubSubClass. If I try SubSubClass (SubClass.Make(..)) I am getting the error that downwards conversion is not allowed.

Comment: You probably want to use an _extension aggregate_; my answer had an example of this, and I edited the answer to point it out.  `return (SubClass.Make(...) with new_component=>new_value, ...)` will use `SubClass.Make` to determine the values of inherited components, and then you use the `with ...` part to specify the values of new components.  If there aren't any new components, then `(SubClass.Make(...) with null record)`.

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to achieve?  What are your requirements for the type?

Answer (score 4):

ajb's answer is ***very*** good, but I hope you'll allow me to "work up" to Ada's OOP facilities because they're actually fairly different than the Java equivalents. -- I'm typing off the top of my head here, so the examples might not be compilable, but should do to get the ideas across.

```
Package Test_1 is
  Type Point is record
   x, y : Integer;
  end record;
  -- Some operations
End Test_1;
```

In the above we are creating a type, but there's a problem here: it exposes the implementation and users can go and change the values directly, which could be disastrous if certain processes/properties need to be ensured. (It also introduces dependance on implementation details.)

In order to address this, we can make the record private and make clients use functions and procedures to alter the internal state -- just like getters and setters (but we haven't touched on any OOP yet).

```
Package Test_2 is
  Type Point is private;

  Function Create( x, y : Integer ) return Point;
  Function Get_X ( P : Point ) return Integer;
  Function Get_Y ( P : Point ) return Integer;
  -- Some more operations.
Private
  Type Point is record
   x, y : Integer;
  end record;

  -- Ada 2012 expression-functions, for brevity.
  Function Create( x, y : Integer ) return Point is ( x => x, y => y );
  Function Get_X ( P : Point ) return Integer is ( P.X );
  Function Get_Y ( P : Point ) return Integer is ( P.Y );
End Test_2;
```

In the above the change is made so that the implementation is private, this allows us to change the implementation (see below) without forcing clients to recompile. (We could change `Test_3` to `Test_2` and it would still work.)

```
Package Test_3 is
  Type Point is private;

  Function Create( x, y : Integer ) return Point;
  Function Get_X ( P : Point ) return Integer;
  Function Get_Y ( P : Point ) return Integer;
  -- Some more operations.
Private
  Type Point is record
   x, y : Float;
  end record;

  -- Ada 2012 expression-functions, for brevity.
  Function Create( x, y : Integer ) return Point is
  ( x => Float(x), y => Float(y) );
  Function Get_X ( P : Point ) return Integer is
  ( Integer(P.X) );
  Function Get_Y ( P : Point ) return Integer is
  ( Integer(P.Y) );
End Test_3;
```

So, as you can see `private` means something different in Ada than it does in Java. Because Ada had this notion of `private` before OOP was added (in Ada 95) it was carried over to the OOP. (Basically the idea is that changes in a private-type's implementation cannot cause a program to change states becoming legal or illegal as a result.)

As you can see, Ada also had the notion of records and indirected access [private types] and even inheritance [derived types]... but Ada still had the notion of types, and especially distinct types that could be prohibited from interacting (a type for length and another for weight), and subtypes [which were types with added constraints] were different enough that it wouldn't be a good fit, and so they needed some way to distinguish between a type and a "type-or-something-derived-from-it" which is where the `'class` attribute comes in:  `Type_Name'Class` denotes a whole branch of an inheritance tree of a `tagged-type`.

```
-- Declare an operation that must be overridden in derived types,
-- and which takes the specific type:
Function Operation( Input : Type_Name ) return Boolean is abstract;

-- Declare an operation that takes the whole class: 
Function Operation( Input : Type_Name'Class ) return Boolean;
```

Because of the rule above, a record that had some private components needs to be in the private portion of the spec so that changes to its internal structure don't impact the legality of the clients.

Now we're at a point roughly analogous to what you're used to in Java: class-definitions and inheritance, but with this added idea that `private` is something dealing with client-use (and packages) rather than, strictly-speaking, the object (or type) itself.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in Java, you don't need `new` to create an object.  `new` specifically allocates an object and returns an *access* to the object.  So this:

```
    return new MasterC'(fTest1=>0.0, fTest2=>0.0); -- This is not working!
```

fails because the function is declared to return a `MasterC`, not an `access MasterC` or any type that is declared as `access MasterC` (or `access all MasterC'class` or anything of the sort).  The function doesn't return an access type at all.  So don't use `new`. Instead, the form will be

```
    return (P => ???);  -- keep reading to see what ??? is
```

The value of `P` here is a `PrivateComponent`.  This is a subtype of `Ada.Finalization.Controlled` with an additional component `P`, so the syntax will look like

```
return (P => (Ada.Finalization.Controlled with P => ???))
```

The value of **that** `P` will be `Private_Part_Pointer`, which **is** an access type (to `Private_Part`), so that's where you'd use `new`.

```
return (P => (Ada.Finalization.Controlled with P => 
    new Private_Part' (ftest1=>0.0, ftest2=>0.0)));
```

It's really not that complicated.  To create a value of a record type, put the values in parentheses with *component-name* `=>` followed by a value for each component.  To create a value of an access type, use `new`.

When returning a `SubC`, things get interesting.  The `SubC` has the same components as a `MasterC`, plus the two you've added.  Thus, it has three components: `P`, `fExtra1`, `fExtra2`.  However, you can't use the name `P` here, because it's in the private part of `MasterClass` and is thus invisible to `SubClass`.  To create a `SubC`, you'll have to call a function to create the `MasterC` part of the `SubC`.  The result will look something like

```
return (MasterClass.Make(f1, f2) with fExtra1 => 0.0, fExtra2 => 0.0);
```

[*Note:* This is called an **extension aggregate**.]

This uses `MasterClass.Make` to create a `MasterC`, which will have a `P` component; the `SubC` function result uses that `P` component with the `fExtra1` and `fExtra2` you've specified to create the three components you need for a `SubC`.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this (I'm at home and don't have a compiler handy), so I may have gotten some of the syntax wrong, or there may be other subtle errors I missed.

**EDIT:** Now that I can use a compiler, I've found that the above two changes make your source compile (the second change has to be implemented in two places); except that `do` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a procedure name, and `printNumObjects` needs a body.  This statement:

```
return This.P.P.fTest1;  -- This is not working!
```

compiles fine with my compiler.